# best approach for table with collapsing rows for another table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

So I'm working on a Django project, where I have to present a list of logs with data. I wrote it so I have two models: Log and ErrorItem. The erroritem has a foreign key to the log.

What I want to do is display a table of all the logs and their data, and when you click on a row, it collapses a into another table of all the related erroritems and their data.

I already found one solution - add a hidden tr, and a script the toggles it. But then that means that the erroritem list is part of the log table - and I don't need that because both tables are not the same.

I know there are probably a lot of solutions for this, so I'm not looking for a straight code answer. I'm just hoping that someone can point me at the right direction - what's the best approach here? Is there some jQuery plugin that makes it simple? Should I use ajax to create the table dynamically through another page?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make an ajax request to fetch the ErrorItem data. Loading ErrorItem data for all log rows and using hidden  would be an overkill.

Comment: No no see I'm already fetching the data dynamically using django, the problem is inserting a div with another table in between rows without messing up the original table

Comment: @YuvalBar-On what is the structure of your html containing the errors?